# Классы и наследование

Tags: javascript, классы

Есть класс Animal его наследуют классы Dog и Cat.
У Animal есть метод sayFrr.
Вопрос в следующем, можно ли сделать так, что б при вызове этого метода на классе Cat туда выводилось имя собаки?

```js
class Animal {
   constructor(name){
       this.name = name;
   }
    sayFrr(){
        return `Animal ${this.name} is not a cat `      
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal{
    bark() {
    return `Dog ${this.name} is barking `;
}   
}
class Cat extends Dog{
    Miu() {
    return `Cat ${this.name} say Miu_miu `;
}   
}
console.log(new Dog('Bobo'));
console.log(new Dog('Bobo').bark());
console.log(new Cat('Katy'));
console.log(new Cat('Katy').Miu());
console.log(new Cat('Katy').sayFrr());
```

Comment: имя какой собаки?

Comment: new Dog('Bobo')

Comment: Почему именно этой собаки? Если нужно конкретно это имя - замени функцию в animal на `return \`Animal Bobo is not a cat\``

Comment: Я пытаюсь разобраться в наследовании и в this. по этому и придумал такой вопрос. 
Возможно есть вариант когда туда будет записываться имя любой другой собаки, вопрос в том как это реализовать.

Comment: Нет, если ты сам не будешь менять эту функцию - при вызове этой функции из объекта cat `this` всегда будет указывать именно на `cat` и соответственно брать его имя

Comment: Наследуя свойства объекта вы получаете только свойства, а не доступ к данным других объектов. Если вы создали кота с наследством собаки, то у него нет доступа к имени ранее созданной вами собаки

Comment: Спасибо) Понял)))